# How to switch DDE and Gnome desktops in Ubuntu

Tags: desktop-environments

after installing DDE on my Ubuntu and use it, can I switch it back to Gnome? If it can, how to do it? thanks

Comment: Sorry I don't know what DDE is, however I can select at login if I want to use LXQt (Lubuntu), MATE (Ubuntu-MATE), XFCE (Xubuntu) or GNOME (Ubuntu) when I login. My Ubuntu install has multiple desktops installed, selected at the greeter/login screen (`sddm` is my selected greeter).  You didn't say which release, so your DM is unknown.

Comment: @guiverc DDE means Deepin Desktop Environment.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]